# Update association by ID other than primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I want to update an association by passing in a key other than the primary key, like social security number:

```
Teacher.find(params[:id]).update({'student_ids'=>['123-45-6789','987-65-4321']})
```

How can I make my Teacher model understand that it will be receiving SSN, and not database IDs?  A SSN uniquely identifies a student.

Edit: I like Pavling's solution, as it keeps the logic in the model.  However this fails:

```
Teacher.new({name:'Miss Molly',student_ssns:['123-45-6789','987-65-4321']})
```

With `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: student_ssns`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If SSN is a unique identifier for your student rows, you *could* make it the primary key instead of the default integer - but convention would advise to leave the 'normal' ID field there.

So how about a method on Teacher which takes `student_ssns` rather than `student_ids`, and inside that method, find the student ids (similar to Kevin Monk's answer)?

```
# teacher.rb
def student_ssns=(ssns)
  student_ids = Student.where(ssn: ssns).pluck(:id)
  update({student_ids: student_ids})
end
```

Then you can use it thus:

```
Teacher.find(params[:id]).student_ssns(['123-45-6789','987.65.4321'])
```

Comment: I like this solution, but this fails:

Teacher.new({name:'Miss Molly',student_ssns:['123-45-6789','987-65-4321']})

With ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: student_ssns

Comment: I've tweaked the method name... sorry, it should have been a 'setter'

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
student_ids = Student.where(ssn:['123-45-6789','987.65.4321']).map(&:id)
Teacher.find(params[:id]).update({'student_ids'=> student_ids})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Pavling's solution, but changing the definition line to:

```
def student_ssns=(ssns)
```

should get it working properly for you.